# Iteration Through Every N-Elements, Put Into One Element (Tuple), and then Every N-Elements, Put Into Another (Tuple)

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to iterate through every 5 elements of a list and comprise of them one tuple, then the 6th element of the same list to be the second tuple - then do the same on the next 5 elements and then 6th.

I've read about

> operator.itemgetter(*items)

I've read also about

> arrays

I was thinking for something like:

```
first_N_element=[generator.next() for i in range(N)]
```

But that cannot take only the next one element and repeat exactly the same operation.

For example, if you have:

```
l = [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],...
```

how we can comprise a new list like this:

```
new_l = [1,2,3,4,5],[6],[7,8,9,10,11],[12],...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve this is via using [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) with *list comprehension* expression:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> l = [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12]

>>> list(chain(*[[[j[0] for j in l[i:i+5]], l[i+5]] for i in range(0, len(l), 6)]))
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [12]]
```

---

**Edit:** As per the comment from user. The expected behavior is to wrap items within list instead of joining the items. In that case it could be done as:

```
>>> l = ('qw','er','ty','ui','op','as','df','gh','jk','l','zx','cv')

>>> list(chain(*[(list(chain(l[i:i+5])), [l[i+5]]) for i in range(0, len(l), 6)]))
[['qw', 'er', 'ty', 'ui', 'op'], ['as'], ['df', 'gh', 'jk', 'l', 'zx'], ['cv']]
```

In that case, the `list` mentioned in question will return:

```
[[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]], [[6]], [[7], [8], [9], [10], [11]], [[12]]]
```

Comment: Built ins and list comprehensions. Beauty

Comment: This is the output:
`>>> l = ('qw','er','ty','ui','op','as','df','gh','jk','l','zx','cv')`
`>>> list(chain(*[[[j[0] for j in l[i:i+5]], l[i+5]] for i in range(0, len(l), 6)]))
[['q', 'e', 't', 'u', 'o'], 'as', ['d', 'g', 'j', 'l', 'z'], 'cv']`

I'm not sure why but I can only say that this is not the desired answer.

Comment: That is because the example you mentioned in Question and this one are having different content. In my example I am accessing `j` with index 0 assuming there is single element which is not the case in the example you mentioned here

Comment: Sorry that I didn't explain it well enough - every element may be comprised of varying number of symbols. So your very nice code can be used only if the element contains one symbol?

Comment: As of now yes. I can update the answer but for that I want to know the desired output for `('qw','er','ty','ui','op','as','df','gh','jk','l','zx','cv')`. Do you want it to return `[['qw', 'er', 'ty', 'ui', 'op'], ['as'], ['df', 'gh', 'jk', 'l', 'zx'], ['cv']]` ?

Comment: Yes, every element within the first five and then only the sixth one. Thank you, Moinuddin!

Comment: I that case the example you mentioned in the question is incorrect. The output of that list should have been `[[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]], [[6]], [[7], [8], [9], [10], [11]], [[12]]]`. Each item wrapped within list. Isn't?

Comment: Yes, I need it regardless of the number of symbols, you're right - that's what I tried to say.

Comment: And actually the wanted behaviour and result should be: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [12]`

Comment: It is not a valid structure in which you can show the value as you mentioned. If you will store the values you mentioned in a variable, you will see the values wrapped in parenthesis like `(...)` which is known as `tuple`. In my solution I am wrapping them within `list` which is `[...]`. In order to convert it into tuple, you will have to replace the first `list(...)` part in my solution to `tuple(...)`

Comment: Your solution is extremely elegant, indeed, thanks, @MoinuddinQuadri!

Answer (score 4):

You could write a generator. Note, this doesn't handle any edge cases and assumes your data is well-behaved:

```
>>> def my_gen(sequence):
...   it = iter(sequence)
...   while True:
...     yield [next(it) for _ in range(6)]
...     yield [next(it)]
...
>>> l = range(1, 7*4 +1)
>>> list(my_gen(l))
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], [14], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], [21], [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27], [28]]
>>>
```

You can improve upon this to fit your needs. For example, using `from itertools import slice` you can deal with "uneven" lists - lists that aren't multiples of 7, giving you back the trailing bits like follows:

```
>>> def my_gen(sequence):
...   it = iter(sequence)
...   while True:
...     six = list(islice(it, 6))
...     if six:
...       yield six
...     yield [next(it)]
...
>>> l = range(1, 7*4 -3)
>>> list(my_gen(l))
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], [14], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], [21], [22, 23, 24]]
>>>
```

Comment: Clever use of a generator

Comment: Yeah, the thing I like about a generator approach is that the logic is clear. No need for figuring out what the heck is going on with the ranges and indices... just yield 6 items in a list, then 1 item in a list... on and on...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Actually it is iterating every 6 elements and then puts the 7th one in a separate element - I need to iterate through every 5 elements and to put the 6th one in a separate one. Could you fix that? I tried changing the value `(islice(it, 5))` but it cannot exit the `while` loop.

Comment: @Xtigyro it seems to work for me... what values are you using to test it?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: The values are of this kind (I cannot share them exactly):
`['00', '09', '*', '*', '1,2,3,4,5,0', 'some_long_word_of_this_kind', '00', '13', '*', '*', '1,3,5,0', 'sth_long_like_this', '30', '08', '*', '*', '1', 'some_long_word', '00', '11', '*', '*', '1,2,3,4,5,6,0', 'some_long_word', '00', '16', '*', '*', '1,3,5,0', 'some_long_word', '00', '04', '*', '*', '6', 'some_long_word', '00', '12', '*', '*', '2,4', 'some_long_word', '00', '07', '*', '*', '6', 'some_long_word_of_this_kind', '00', '16', '1', '*', '*', 'some_long_word', '00', '12', '*', '*', '6', 'some_long_word']`

Answer (score 1):

Right: you probably don't want to do this with a single operation.  Instead, use a pair of related operations.  Please note that your syntax does not produce lists: you've left off the outermost pair of brackets in each of your list assignment statements.

I'll leave this in a loop, to make sure you understand the logic.  You can also put the entire process into a list comprehension, in a single line, but I'm guessing that you'd find it hard to read.

```
ord_list = [[i] for i in range(24)]
print ord_list

new_l = []
for n in range(0, len(ord_list)-5, 6):
    new_l += [[ord_list[n+i][0] for i in range(5)]] + [ord_list[n+5]]
print new_l
```

Output:

```
[[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23]]
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11], [12, 13, 14, 15, 16], [17], [18, 19, 20, 21, 22], [23]]
```

Is that what you needed?

Comment: 24? I don't know how many elements there will be or I need to count them before starting here?

Comment: No, you don't need to count them.  note that the only place **24** appears is when I generate the original list.

Comment: What other values can be used instead of '24' and how I determine that value? This may be a very dummy question, forgive my ignorance. Thank you for your efforts!

Comment: You don't.  You put whatever list you've already build into **ord_list**.

Comment: Yes, I got it now but I guess the code is written explicitly if every element contains only one symbol? Thank you, Prune!

Comment: Quite welcome; I'm glad we solved your problem.
Do remember to up-vote helpful things, if you haven't already.  I've marked both of the other answers, as they're nice work.

Comment: Yes, I did so, including your very nice code but my rating is still below 15 (I'm quite new here) and it is registered but not publicly seen. By the way, I need this to work with not only one symbol as an element.